# Order by using Sum Points in Yii?

Tags: yii

```
 $resource_cnt = ShopVisituser::model()->findAll(array(
            'select' => '*, sum(points) as amt',
            'condition' => 'user_id=:user_id AND merchant_id=:merchant_id',
            'order' => 'amt DESC',
            'params' => array(':user_id' => $datas->user_id, ':merchant_id' => $datas->merchant_id))
        );
```

I can't order by sum(points) as amt Desc.Why?how to order that Sum(points) in Yii.

Comment: Are you trying to get a sum without grouping your results?

Comment: can you give a spanshot of the data by CVarDumper::dump($resource_cnt) ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a function on your Model, for example:

```
public function scopes() {
   return array(
      'byamt' => array('order' => 'amt DESC'),
   );
}
```

Now, you can use your query like this:

```
$resource_cnt = ShopVisituser::model()->byamt()->findAll(array(
        'select' => '*, sum(points) as amt',
        'condition' => 'user_id=:user_id AND merchant_id=:merchant_id',
        'params' => array(':user_id' => $datas->user_id, ':merchant_id' => $datas->merchant_id))
    );
```